# How to squash commits after rebasing

Tags: git, github

I rebased my code (rebasing consisted of 21 steps) then after rebasing I want to squash commits. when I write git rebase -i Head~3 it doesn't pick the last 3 commits it picks more than that. I though okay let it be that more, then it asks me to rebase again. why? is it normal? what is happening?

Comment: Run `git log --decorate --oneline --graph HEAD~3..` and include the output (cut and paste it) in your question.

Comment: thanks but i already solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that the first rebase was not fully completed.

If possible, try the first rebase again (in a new clone for instance), and after completion, do a `git status` to check:

- you are on the right branch
- the status is "clear"

Only then try your second rebase for squashing.

As the [OP Dato Nefaridze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14575208/dato-nefaridze) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64675495/how-to-squash-commits-after-rebasing/64676016?noredirect=1#comment114371348_64676016), it seems the initial rebase was not done properly:

> I solved problem by rebasing again, nothing bad happened

Comment: no first one was successfully completed,git showed me that operation was successfully done.

Comment: @DatoNefaridze does a git log shows you the last three commits you want to squash?

Comment: I don't understand. anyway i solved problem by rebasing again, nothing bad happened

Comment: @DatoNefaridze OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.